# Discord JS , Node JS and Reaction Flags

Tags: node.js, discord, flags

I have been scratching my head trying to figure this out and I cannot find a solution for it.
Basically I am trying to use the flags to chose a user's language.
I cannot figure out how to react with US flag, French flag and so on.
I have tried to get all the emojis that client has access to using:

``` const emojis = client.emojis.cache.map((e) => `${e} **-** \`:${e.name}:\``).join(', '); ```

I cannot find the flags or any other emojis.
I know I can use :smile: or other but doesn't work with flags no matter what I try.
Has anyone got an idea how to get this sorted?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Found a websited called `https://www.emojicopy.com/` which makes copying flags 100x easier. Saved me from tracking down how to copy flags in discord.